# Stateless objects are always thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In [Java Concurrency In Practice, Section 2.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=stateless%20objects%20are%20always%20thread-safe%20Stateless%20Factorization&source=bl&ots=uoXAA2qNgA&sig=HdkaPXiubzXg8_0Ds5eldYi4r6w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIzNK6teKYyAIV1SmICh38FwUG#v=onepage&q=stateless%20objects%20are%20always%20thread-safe%20Stateless%20Factorization&f=false), it states:

> Stateless objects are always thread-safe.

And gives the following class as an example:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class StatelessFactorization implements Servlet {
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp){
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = factor(i);
        encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);       // <-- isn't it possible for resp to be
                                                 //     modified by mult. threads at once?
    }
}
```

---

## Question:

As indicated in the code above, what happens if multiple threads try to modify the same `ServletResponse` variable.

From my understanding of memory allocation, the above class does not seem completely thread safe.

While the reference to the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` are put on the local stack for the calling thread, the actual objects are stored on the heap --which is shared between all threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here the stateless object is `StatelessFactorization` class. It's stateless because it has no own state, namely it has no instance fields. Thus this object is thread-safe. The `resp` is another object implementing the `ServletResponse` interface and it may or may not be thread-safe. Here the thread-safety of `resp` is not discussed.

Comment: That makes sense I guess, but it seems confusing that they would use this as an example -- since calling `StatelessFactorization` methods can lead to something that is not thread-safe. Using primitive (or any immutable) parameters would have been less confusing to me.

Comment: @bcorso, I guess the book authors wanted to show some example which is close to the real world. Though, of course, I cannot say exactly.

Answer (score 8):

When you make an HTTP request that is going to be handled by a servlet, its `service` method will be invoked. If you have multiple clients making multiple requests at the same time, each request may be handled by a different thread. However, the instances of `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` that each thread will receive are **different**, so you are not going to have multiple threads modifying the same instances of those objects. Each thread modifies its own instances of them. Of course, that doesn't happen by magic, your servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) is the one that handles the thread creation and the allocation of those instances for you in this specific case.

It's a confusing example, because you cannot assume that you can always modify whatever you want inside that method and everything will be magically thread safe. However, it's an interesting example of a method that usually is executed by multiple threads in a real world application.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context!